# How to ignore some json fields in LogBook response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logbook

I need to ignore some fields in response of `Zalando Logbook` logging

For example, if I have a Java response class:

```
class MyResponse {
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldTwo;
    private String fieldThree;
}
```

I want to have a LOGGED response json:

```
{
    "fieldOne": "abcd",
    "fieldThree": "dcba"
}
```

I've tried to use BodyFilters, but it's still not working. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69603219/how-to-exclude-a-specific-property-or-data-type-from-log-request-in-logbook

Answer (score 1):

It depends what library do you use to serialize your class to JSON. If you use JSON-Jackson library you will need to add `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the field(s) that you want to ignore. So your class should look like this:

```
class MyResponse {
    private String fieldOne;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private String fieldTwo;
    private String fieldThree;
}
```

Read this article for more info: [Jackson Ignore Properties on Marshalling](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization). Also, there is an open source MgntUtils library that provides a `JsonUtils` class that allows you very simply to serialize classes to JSON String and parse them from JSON String to class instance. This util is a thing wrapper over JSON-Jackson library and, for simple cases, saves you writing any configuration related to the Jackson lib. Here is [the Javadoc for JsonUtils class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The MgntUtils library can be obtained as [Maven artifact from Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including Javadoc and source code). This library is written and maintained by me